# Can One Compare the Margin of Error of a 7-point Likert Scale vs 9- point Likert Scale

Tags: error, likert

In many of our product tests and attitudinal studies where we ask for rating on Overall Liking (a product), product managers either use a Likert scale of 7 or 9-points with each point anchored (ex. 7= Extremely like, 6=Moderately like. etc.)  We now want to set a standard or common procedure in measuring Overall Liking for future surveys.  We have read reviews/comments on the merits, findings on number of response categories for Likert Scales.  However, we would like to use the results of our past studies to determine which of the 2 is better (and more reliable?) for our use.  Our surveys have sample sizes of at least 100.

We computed for the MOEs of the results of Overall Liking ratings of our various studies.  We have observed that more often, the MOEs for a 7-point rating scale is lower than that of a 9-point scale.  Can we use this as empirical evidence to support our choice for a 7-point rating scale?  We understand that there are many factors to look at but we are unsure if looking at the MOE makes sense.

Comment: If I compute the MOE for, say, diameters of oranges in miles rather than inches, it will be tiny indeed! So before it makes any sense to compare two numbers *they have to be expressed in the same units.* Your two Likert scales are not in the same units. (They're actually not in any units at all, because they aren't even of interval type.) That raises all kinds of auxiliary questions, but for a start you should at least attempt to find a conversion from one scale to the other so you can compare the MOEs legitimately.

Comment: Thank you for your help - whuber!  If I need to have comparable scales, for the 9-point scale, maybe, I could just combine 8 and 9 to denote a "7" and 1 and 2 (in the 9 pt scale) to denote a "1".  That will reduce the 9-pt to a 7-pt.  Of course, I will have to review the distribution of the scores.  If I see that the distribution for 1 and 2, 8 and 9 are close to each other, then I can combine their ratings.  I do not know if this does not even make sense at all.  I have very little background in stat so this may make no sense at all.  Sorry.